# Probability of winning 5th event if 4 won already and probability of winning is 0.5

Tags: probability

If the probability to win an event is 50% and i won 4 events in a row , what is the probability of me winning the 5th event?

Comment: If the events are independent, then it is still 50%.

Comment: If the probability to win an event is 50%, then probability of winning an event is 50%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past coin tosses affect the latest one if you know about them?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139388/past-coin-tosses-affect-the-latest-one-if-you-know-about-them)

Comment: The question is incomplete. You need to tell if the events are independent or not.